# React: Component receives data and returns iteration of components, but can't Add Conditional?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I have a simple example of my problem below:

Functional Component

Returns ItemList that has takes in `data` (array of objects).
ItemList `renderItem` property takes that `data` and can iterate through with each element represented by `item`.
Within `renderItem` property, you can also return `<Item></Item>` for each element.

This works, but my issue is when I add a ternary (conditional) in nested return statement. I don't get why this won't work.

The errors I get are along the line of JSX must have one parent element. But it does, with the `<Fragment></Fragment>` or if you are only looking at the nested return only `<Item></Item>`. I get other errors as well.

```
const ExampleComponent = () => {
  const [someState, setSomeState] = useState(true);

  return (
    <Fragment>
      <ItemList
        items={data}
        renderItem={(item) => {
          const { id, title, description } = item;

          return (
            {someState ? (
            <Item
              id={id}
              key={id}
            >
              <h1>{title}</h1>
              <p>{description}</p>
            </Item>) ? : (
              <Item>
              </Item>
            )}
          );
          
        }}
      />
    </Fragment>
  );
};

export default ExampleComponent;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
return (
  <>
    {someState ? (
      <Item
        id={id}
        key={id}
      >
        <h1>{title}</h1>
        <p>{description}</p>
      </Item>) : (
      <Item>
      </Item>
     )}
   </>
);
```